What plan do I need to purchase to add a donation form from Civi on my website?
At Amantani (www.amantani.org.uk) we switched to CiviCRM last year. Since we'll be improving our website soon, we want to know exactly what plan do we need to purchase in order to be able to have a subscription and donation form from Civi directly integrated into our new Wordpress site.
Also, I understand we would also need a Civi plugin. Are there any considerations we need to keep in mind regarding that? Is it for free?
Thank you very much.

are you using civicrm Spark - or just standard CiviCRM - civi already comes with subscription and donation options - just enable civicontribute if it is not already enabled, and then read https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/online-contributions/#page-or-post-in-wordpress

hey, thanks! ill look into it. we are using standard civiCRM, but I can see the civi contribute option, so I think we are ok. :)

Thx. will add as an Answer, pls accept it - or you could it it yourself to get more karma
